# Прокрутка iframe относительно страницы

Tags: html, css, iframe

На странице есть 2 iframe.

```
<body>
<iframe id="play" class="menu-frame" src="menu.php" 
 frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<iframe id="cont" class="cont-frame" src="/page_1.html" 
 frameborder="0" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; border: none"
 allowtransparency="true" ></iframe>
</body>
```

В первом - плеер, во втором - содержимое. Плеер в верхнем правом углу. Но при прокрутке основной страницы он должен съезжать наверх, вместе с содержимым, а сейчас он фактически `fixed` и всегда наверху. В общем, нужно, чтобы он вел себя не как `iframе`, а как обычный `relative` блок на странице, при этом находясь в `iframe`. Можно ли как-то это побороть при условии, что `iframe` все-таки два?

[image: 1]

Comment: @andreymal сложность в том, чтобы страница перезагружалась, а плеер продолжал играть. А ajax`ом уже нельзя. Вот и приходится выкручиваться, что в одном фрейме контент, и в нем можно переходить по ссылкам, а во втором сам плеер, который не зависит от контента.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36377/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry-n--iframe--).

Answer (score 1):

У вас в примере кода и в описании 2 ифрейма рядом, а на картинке один ифрейм в другом. Предлагаю рассмотреть пример, написанный согласно вашему описанию и уточнить что же вы имели в виду: https://jsfiddle.net/vdwLh7yy/

html

```
<iframe id="play" class="menu-frame" src="http://ya.ru/nopagefortest" 
 frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<iframe id="cont" class="cont-frame" src="http://ya.ru/nopagefortest" 
 frameborder="0" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; border: none"
 allowtransparency="true" ></iframe>
```

css

```
.menu-frame {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  float: right;
}
.cont-frame {border: 1px solid #f00 !important;}
```

Comment: один в другом потому что у <iframe id="play"> position:absolute. Продублирую, задумка в том, чтобы страница перезагружалась, а плеер продолжал играть. А ajax`ом делать нельзя. Вот и приходится выкручиваться, что в одном фрейме контент, и в нем можно переходить по ссылкам, а во втором сам плеер, который не зависит от контента.